# How can I migrate to new twitter API?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have error:

> tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'message': 'The Twitter REST API v1 is no
>   longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1.
>   https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.', 'code': 68}]

What should I do?
How can I migrate to new twitter API?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not using the latest `tweepy` version. Try to install it directly from github (2.1 version now):

```
git clone https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git
python setup.py install
```

Hope this is it.

If not, add the code that produces an error.

Comment: I am getting this error now after doing clone&install as suggested above
TweepError: [{'message': 'Bad Authentication data', 'code': 215}]

Comment: Then, check your keys and tokens. I don't think this is related to tweepy.